# SQL Server hogging CPU and memory - caused by system clock change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sharepoint-2007

I've been developing using Sharepoint 2007 on a VM, and recently tested some functionality by trying to change the system date.

Ever since then SQL server has been using 50% CPU and a lot of memory.

I've limited it's memory, but have no idea how to fix the problem.

More details: The process using 50% cpu (1 core out of 2 for the vm) is sqlserver.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with Sharepoint itself.

By disabling the Search Service (which I don't need to run on my VM) the CPU usage of SQL Server went back to normal after a restart.

To disable this, go in to Sharepoint 3.0 Central Admin > Operations > Services on Server

Stop Office SharePoint Server Search.

Comment: that's good to know because we're getting into sharepoint ourselves here.  which version of sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Activity Monitor to know most of processor time consuming processes. You can run activity monitor from Management folder. 
For query level details use SQL Profiler. Working with profiler is explained the best here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/

Answer (score 1):

try restarting (either the instance or the whole server).  I'm not 100% sure if changes to memory limits take without a restart.  restarting will clear out all of the memory and processes as well.

Comment: I had already thought of that, strangely enough! The problem comes back when the Sql instance starts.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some known issues with slow performance with SQL Server 2005 on a VMWare instance (assuming that's what you're using), at least according to my random googling.

Have you tried looking at [SQL Server 2005 Performance Dashboard Reports](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=1d3a4a0d-7e0c-4730-8204-e419218c1efc&displaylang=en) for bottlenecks?